# IBM WebSphere MQ - how do I read only MQMT_REQUEST messages

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

I'm developing windows service that serves two purposes.

1. It is a proxy to WebSphere MQ for web application that asks other
   systems - it sends request and second system replies.
2. It is a server that should respond to other system requests - other system sends request, the service responds.

In scenario 1 I'm waiting for response with specific correlation ID. However, in scenario 2 I'm waiting for any message that is a request. How can I avoid situation that I will read the response from scenario 2 and treat it like a request in scenario 2? I would like to filter the messages that I read in scenario 2 only to messages that have Message Type `MQMT_REQUEST`.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two different input queues.  The overhead of selecting the right messages from the queue when there are mixed message types is considerably greater, in terms of program logic and WMQ indexing, than to simply create two queues.

Typically in a Service Oriented Architecture, the service endpoint queues are well-known and the reply-to queues are either dynamic or at least not well-known since the service provider needs only to look at the reply-to fields for the return address.  In this case your application is both a service provider and a service consumer.  The queue it uses as an endpoint for the service it provides should be a well-known queue that all of its clients send messages to.  The queue it uses for replies to its service requests should be an entirely different queue.

One good example of why is that it is common when enhancing a service to provide a different endpoint queue for the new version.  For example a service that returns a customer name based on an account number might live on a queue `SVC.CUST.LOOKUP.V01`.  If the service is enhanced a new version can be made available on `SVC.CUST.LOOKUP.V02`.  Requestors of the service then have the ability to migrate from the `V1` queue to the `V2` queue on their own schedule rather than requiring them all to convert at once.

You would definitely *not* want your application's reply-to queue to be associated with its service endpoint queue in this situation.  The two serve entirely different functions, are subject to entirely different change control and enhancement schedules, etc.

Comment: I cannot do this. I have one input queue and one output queue. I cannot change this configuration.

Comment: Do you know how can I set selector. I can't find any info how to do this in .NET.

Comment: It is impossible to change this configuration. I need to find the solution when I get requests and replies in the same queue.

Comment: I'll ask Shashi to reply concerning the selectors.  That said, what is limiting you to one queue?  If you have access to set selectors, then you aren't using vendor-supplied code. The only cost of adding a queue is administrative.  Is it really that much more expensive in your organization to get a queue added than to work around the administrative hurdles by using complex application code?

Comment: My client has this kind of configuration. I'm using standard MQ API. I'm not using XMS.

Comment: I emailed Shashi but he's in India where it is after hours now, and I'm not sure when he'll see this.  However as a consultant (which I was for the last 5 years) or a vendor, I'd explain to the client that the solution is far less expensive to implement and operate, as well as more reliable with a second queue.  *Make sure the client signs off on both the additional cost and the risk inherent in this design* in order that this does not blow back on you.  What they are asking for is not just "not a best practice" but is bad enough to fall into the category of an anti-pattern. Tread carefully.

Comment: They have many systems that use this configuration. I guess they're mostly using JMS that solves this problem for developers.

Comment: MQ .NET API does not provide a way set selector yet. I second T.Robs solution of using two queues.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same service, read messages from the queue in one place (probably your main loop, right?), when a message arrives check its correlation ID and see if it's a scenario-1 response. Decide which processing to perform based on that test.